# Magento Add to Cart on the Grid view

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new to this whole website thing. 
I need to remove the "add to Cart" in Catalog I have tried everything but Cant get rid of it, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the button code in app/design/frontend/default/{THEME NAME}/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

**Tipp**: If you're searching related theme files, you can go to your backend, System -> Configuration, then choose in the sidebar under ADVANCED the link Developer. Choose the Shop View in the upper left corner and then you can activate "Template Path Hints".

Don't do that in production, since it "ruins" the design with all the hints.

Comment: Nope. That there is the most searched answer from the web, tried it, But the button doesnt get removed.

Comment: Did you try the tipp? Then you can see the real path, since parts of the thema may be taken from magentos default theme.